# Android's Add to Homescreen basics

Tags: android, ios, mobile, homescreen

I have read a number of articles about adding a link to the home screen of Android but am failing to get the icon and label I intend.

It would appear that the more recent articles are focusing on this feature as something to add links which will launch websites as full screen apps, leveraging new functionality in the OS.

This is not what I'm trying to do; I would like to add a simple, labelled icon to the home screen and have it launch the web page in a browser.

Currently, I believe that this is done with these elements in the `head` block:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="MyIconLabel">
<meta name="application-name" content="MyIconLabel">
```

...for both iOS and Android.

Is this correct as of October 2017?

Note: The website I am adding the customised home screen label and icon to are not progressive web sites, just regular web sites which I would like to launch from user's home screens.

*Some* links I've drawn from:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen
- http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/home-screen-web-apps-android-chrome-31
- http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the instructions on this site provided the required manifest file and inclusion directions:

https://realfavicongenerator.net/

Comment: Amazing tool!  Thanks for sharing!